# SQLAlchemy - Query show results where records exist in both table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an items table that is related to an item_tiers table. The second table consists of inventory receipts for an item in the items table. There can be 0 or more records in the item_tiers table related to a single record in the items table. How can I, using query, get only records that have 1 or more records in item tiers....

results = session.query(Item).filter(???).join(ItemTier)

Where the filter piece, in pseudo code, would be something like ...
if the item_tiers table has one or more records related to item.

Comment: There is, and i was really over thinking this. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a foreign key defined between tables, SA will figure the join condition for you, no need for additional filters.

> There is, and i was really over thinking this. Thanks for the fast response. – Ominus

Answer (score 0):

```
results = session.query(Item).join(ItemTier).filter(Item.foreign_key=ItemTier.column_with_keys).all()
```